# Check if textbox or datepicker has changed before running stored procedure C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, stored-procedures

I am seeking an easy way to check if a textbox or a datepicker has changed since the form was opened. If it did then run stored procedure, else just skip it and run the ones have have changed.

**What I have:**

```
internal static string oldAvgRate;
internal static string oldOTRate;
internal static string ratetype;
internal static string ratetypeOT;  
private string UpdateRate(string dateFrom, string newRate, string oldRate, string ratetype, string description){
    string connectionString = "datasource=;port=;username=;password=";
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UpdateRate", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_DateFrom", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = dateFrom;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_NewAmount", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = newRate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_OldAmount", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = oldRate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_RateType", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ratetype;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_Description", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = description;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

        connection.Close();
        return newRate;      
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    return null;
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    oldAvgRate = UpdateRate(dfAvgR.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), txtAvgR.Text, oldAverageRate, ratetype, txtdescriptionAvgR.Text);
    oldOTRate = UpdateRate(dfOTR.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), txtOTR.Text, oldOTRate, ratetypeOT, txtdescriptionOTR.Text);
}
```

For example: if `txtAvgR.Text` and/or `df.AvgR.Value` has changed then run `oldAvgRate` else skip and run `oldOTRate` if `txtOTR.Text` and/or `df.OTR.Value` has changed else don't run any of them and display MessageBox("Nothing has changed").

How can I achieve this? What's the best approach in my case? Thank you.

**Update based on suggestion from @Picnic8 and @Robert Harvey:**

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtAvgR" TextChanged="textChangedEventHandler" IsEnabled="False"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txtOTR" TextChanged="textChangedEventHandler" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

**C#:**

```
private bool hasChangedFlag;

// TextChangedEventHandler delegate method.
private void textChangedEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{        
    hasChangedFlag = true;
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (hasChangedFlag)
    {
    oldAvgRate = UpdateRate(dfAvgR.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), txtAvgR.Text, oldAvgRate, ratetype, txtdescriptionAvgR.Text);
    oldOTRate = UpdateRate(dfOTR.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), txtOTR.Text, oldOTRate, ratetypeOT, txtdescriptionOTR.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("Done", "Test", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
    else
    {    
    MessageBox.Show("Nothing has changed", "Test", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Set a boolean flag on the `AfterUpdate` event of `txtAvgR` and `dv.AvgR`.  Check that flag in your `btnSave_Click` method.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Robert. I don't have any idea where to start, I'm still learning. Can you please show me how you would do it? I appreciate it.

Comment: Isn't there an event listener template for textbox text.changed? I'd suggest having this text.changed event listener set a flag and your btnSave refer to this flag
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank for the suggestion Doug. There is not text.changed event yet. I was not sure if I should you the text.change event or a tag. I am grateful for any support.

Answer (score 5):

Based on what @Robert Harvey suggested, here is a way to implement the flag.

**UPDATED**

```
private bool txtAvgRHasChangedFlag;
private bool txtOTRRHasChangedFlag;

// TextChangedEventHandler delegate method.
private void textChangedEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{        
    var control = sender as TextBox;

    if (control.Name == "txtAvgR")
        txtAvgRHasChangedFlag = true;
    else if (control.Name == "txtOTR")
        txtOTRHasChangedFlag = true;
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtAvgRHasChangedFlag)
    {
        oldAvgRate = UpdateRate(dfAvgR.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), txtAvgR.Text, oldAvgRate, ratetype, txtdescriptionAvgR.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Done", "Test", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }

    if (txtOTRRHasChangedFlag)
    {
        oldOTRate = UpdateRate(dfOTR.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), txtOTR.Text, oldOTRate, ratetypeOT, txtdescriptionOTR.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Done", "Test", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }

    if (!txtOTRRHasChangedFlag && !txtAvgRHasChangedFlag)
    {    
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing has changed", "Test", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        return;
    }
}
```

Now in your  XAML simply reference this event delegate like this

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtAvgR" TextChanged="textChangedEventHandler" IsEnabled="False"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtOTR" TextChanged="textChangedEventHandler" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

Comment: Superb answer, thank you for your help! It is exactly what I was looking for. However, it does not work. Even though I followed your advice, when I leave everything unchanged, both stored procedures run on btnSave_Click. It's like the if statement is nonexistent. Only the first part of the statement gets executed. Can you please see my updated question? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, how can I add SelectionDateChanged to the delegate method and use it for a datepicker based on your example?

Comment: From what i read, This event fires when the TextBox control is created and initially populated with text. If i am not wrong, it mean you should disregard the flag assignment the first time (when the control is created) Put a break point inside the event method and tell me if it enters when you simply start your solution please. If it does, you just found the problem :)

Comment: I wish I could understand the first part of your reply. I have put a breakpoint on the line: hasChangedFlag = true; When I start the solution it does not enter. What can I do? Please advise.

Comment: Hmm when I test it locally it works for me, can you put a breakpoint on the line if(hasChangedFlag) as well and observe the flow of the application if you type something inside the box and press your button after. On my pc it enters the event handler (hasChangedFlag = true) and the if statement when I press the button. Also just to be sure, initialize the flag value to false.

Comment: I put a break point at if(hasChangedFlag). Now it enters when I start the solution. When I look at Locals -> txtAvgR -> Static members -> TextChangedEvent, I have a few Xs'(errors?) on: DeclaringMethod (Static members - NonPublic Memembers, _COMPlusExceptionCode -532462766 int, Non-Public members, GenericParameter Atributes and GenericParameterAtributs). I have no idea how to fix this. Can you please help me? I lack the knowledge to debug this on my own. I really want to get to the bottom of this. If I set hasChangedFllag = false; and then the else part gets executed (nothing has changed).

Comment: Oh i know why ! you have the same event handler for both oldAvgRate  and oldOTRate. You need an extra if on the btn_SaveClick. Let me update my answer for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156954/discussion-between-picnic8-and-icosmin).